# Two of one to many relationship hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have some relational objects like this : 
[image]

The user has one to many relation with promotion and store has the same too.

User Class has this code

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "promotion_owner", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = true), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "promotion_id"))
private List<Promotion> promotions;
```

and store class has this one

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "promotion_owner", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "store_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "promotion_id"))
private List<Promotion> promotions;
```

And the problem is when I try to create new promotion it says user_id does not have a default value, is there any way to add all needed information for the new promotion at the same time?

I do this to create new promotion by the way in PromotionController class:

```
public void addPromotion(Promotion promotion, Integer storeId, Integer userId) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    try {
        if(promotionRepository.exists(promotion.getPromotionId())) {
            logger.error("Promosyon ID = " + promotion.getPromotionId() + " is already created, should be unique !");
        } else {
            promotion.setDateCreated(dateFormat.format(date));
            promotionRepository.save(promotion);
            storeService.addPromotion(promotion, storeId);
            customUserDetailsService.addPromotion(promotion, userId);
        }
    } catch(PromotionServiceException exception) {
        throw new PromotionServiceException("Internal Server Exception while creating promotion !");
    }
}
```

This creates promotion object successfully but can't create the relation between store - promotion and user - promotion

Thanks.

Comment: Try reversing:  
           
            promotionRepository.save(promotion);  
            storeService.addPromotion(promotion, storeId);  
           

So that it's  

            storeService.addPromotion(promotion, storeId);  
            promotionRepository.save(promotion);

Comment: I believe you need to call `promotionRepository.save(promotion);` last.  Setup everything first, then persist the `promotion`

Comment: `promotionRepository.save(promotion);` saves your promotion... but you need to pass the **saved** promotion to your other services!

Comment: @SüleymanGÜNDÜZ  Are you populating the promotion instance with all it's dependencies (store, user)?